# How to get a random choice back from select nested lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have a simple nested list of variables which are 6 players names. As seen below.

```
player_options = [[person_1, person_2],[person_3, person_4], [person_5, person_6]]
```

What I want to get is a random variable from the first nest, and then one from either the second or third. I am currently able to select a random one from the first nest and second **OR** third however not second **AND** third?

The code I currently have for this is

```
pair_1 = random.choice(player_options[0]) + random.choice(player_options[1])
```

How would I go about getting a random choice from nest [0] and a random choice from either nest [1] or [2]?

If you need anymore information just let me know!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the probability to be uniform for all players in lists 2 and 3, you can just concat the lists for this:

```
pair_1 = random.choice(player_options[0]) + random.choice(player_options[1] + player_options[2])
```

If you want first a 50%-50% split choice between the lists, then uniform among the chosen list, you can chain 2 `choice` calls like:

```
pair_1 = random.choice(player_options[0]) + random.choice(random.choice(player_options[1:3]))
```

Note that these produce different probability of being chosen for members of list 2 and 3 in case their length differs. So you should choose the one fitting your purpose.

Comment: This works with the edit you just made! I got S. Ferard's answer to work first however this works aswell! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

What about

```py
biggest_index = len(player_options) - 1 # Get the biggest/last index
second_choice = random.randint(1,biggest_index) # Chose a random index between the second (1) and the last one
pair_1 = random.choice(player_options[0]) + random.choice(player_options[second_choice])
```

or do it by using the choice function twice the second time:

```py
second_choice = random.choice(player_options[1:]) # Choose random element after first index
pair_1 = random.choice(player_options[0]) + random.choice(second_choice)
```

Comment: Unfortuantely I cant change it into other lists due to the later steps im planning on making. Normally thats what id do, thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply join the last two nest and make a random choice inside the joined list.

```
pair_1 = random.choice(player_options[0]) + random.choice(player_options[1]+player_options[2])
```

Comment: This works exactly how i was looking for, thanks a lot!!